# ¿Cómo hago para que me aparezca en una ventana el resultado del número mayor de 3 números?

Tags: javascript

Porque me aparece las ventanas de *ingrese un número*, ¿pero el resultado ya no?, en la consola me aparece.

```js
console.log("Cual es mayor?")
let num1 = window.prompt("Ingrese un número");
let num2 = window.prompt("Ingrese un número");
let num3 = window.prompt("Ingrese un número");

//determinar el mayor
if(num1>num2 && num1>num3){
    console.log("El mayor número es:" + num1);
}
else if(num2>num1 && num2>num3){
    console.log("El mayor número es:" + num2);
}
else if(num3>num1 && num3>num2){
     console.log("El mayor número es:" +num3);
}
```

Comment: Para mostrar alertas se utiliza `alert()` en lugar de `console.log()`. ;)

Comment: entiendo, gracias!

Comment: El usuario normal no entra a la consola de desarrollo ni tiene idea de su existencia. Considera **no usar** `console.log` como forma de interacción con el usuario final. Por cierto, `this` en el ámbito global hace referencia a un objeto `Window`, así que puedes utilizar `alert` y `prompt` directamente.

Answer (score 1):

Como te mencionan en los comentarios, debes usar `alert` en lugar de `console.log`.

Te dejo una variante del ejercicio tratando los números ingresados en los `prompt` como un arreglo y con la función `Math.max()` que te retorna el número mayor entre los elementos del arreglo dado.

```js
let num1 = window.prompt("Ingrese un número");
let num2 = window.prompt("Ingrese un número");
let num3 = window.prompt("Ingrese un número");

let numeros = [num1, num2, num3];

alert("El mayor número es: " + Math.max(...numeros));
```