# obtener el máximo valor de tres opciones

Tags: vscode

```
let num1 = 13;
let num2 = 24;
let num3 = 7; 

function numMayor(num1, num2, num3) {
    if (num1>=num2 && num1>=num3){
        return num1;
    } else if (num2>=num1 && num2>=num3) {
        return  num2;
    } else if (num3>=num1 && num3>=num2) {
        return num3;
    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. La pregunta está incompleta. ¿Qué problema tienes y con qué lenguaje? ¿De casualidad tiene algo que ver con [esto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/603543/169744)?

Comment: El IDE (VS Code en este caso) nada tiene que ver con la pregunta. Pulsa en [edit], describe el problema, y pon en las etiquetas a qué lenguaje haces referencia.